# Connect mongo and sapper server with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, svelte, sapper

I am working in a sapper / svelte project and I need to build the sapper project and connect it to a mongodb (I need to start mongo compose from docker-compose.yml)

At the moment I was trying to connect the db to the local mongo on port localhost: 27017 but it can't establish the connection. What should I do?
Here there is my docker-compose

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  myapp:
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      update_config:
        delay: 30s
        parallelism: 1
        failure_action: rollback
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

and here my dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY static static
COPY emails emails

COPY package.json .
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm install

COPY __sapper__/build __sapper__/build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "__sapper__/build/index.js"]
```

Also what should I do to start the mongo deployment directly from compose? I have mongo on docker but I should start both directly from compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    image: yourimage
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    environment: 
        - MONGODB_URL=mongodb://yourip/yourdb     
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "yourportsdb:yourportsdb"
```

it is not necessary to authenticate the mongo with password and user, eventually it passes the environments as suggested @Jihoon Yeo

Answer (score 1):

I think mongo service should be added to services of docker-compose.yml.

for example.

```
services:
   mongodb:
      image: mongo
      restart: always
      environment:
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Then, the node application can access to mongodb by the service name.(ex. mongodb:27017).

I think this URL will help.
https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo